# Convert String to Datetime for SqlServer with C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Hello I have a String of this type: `20160104` I should convert it into format of `SqlServer datetime` with c#, how can I do? I have try with this:

```
DataUltimaVariazione = Convert.ToDateTime("20160104");
```

but visual studio give me an error

Comment: Where did this come from? Why is it a *string* instead of a DateTime value? If this came from a `date` or `datetime` column, retrieve it as DateTime, *don't* convert it to text

Comment: it's read from a file

Comment: you should work with SqlCommand class and Parameters. or you can use this: `Date.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyddMM", provider)`

Comment: Nobody asked but which part is month exactly?

Comment: @rikideveloper you can parse the text to a DateTime value as shown in the answers, but why don't you use BCP, BULK INSERT or SSIS to import flat files ?

Comment: @SonerGönül this looks like the unseparated date format so this *is* unambiguously translated to `yyyyMMdd` in SQL Server. Mixing up this order would show an unusual temperament on the part of the file's author. Think Hannibal Lecter. Or that guy that types � in textboxes

Comment: try this var dateTime = new SqlDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact("20160104", "yyyyddMM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
var myResultDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20160104", 
                                       "yyyyMMdd", 
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert a string to datetime:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("20160104", "yyyyMMdd",
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You could also use DateTime.TryParseExact (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) which gives you more control on wrong formatted datetime strings:

```
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParse("20160104", "yyyyMMdd",
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
}
```

Comment: thank you i have solve with this code